# Is it always possible to construct this integer sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, integers, products

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of monotonically increasing, positive integers. How can one construct another sequence $a_n$, again positive integers, such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{A_n}{\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^n a_k} = 1$$

Is it even always possible to construct such a sequence?

The obvious thing is to choose $a_{n+1}$ to be $\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}$, but its not always guaranteed that this will be an integer. I tried to use $a_{n+1} = \lfloor \frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n} \rfloor$, but I cant seem to work it out. For sequences like $A_n = k^n$ it is very easy to construct $a_n$ if $k$ is an integer itself. What about $A_n =\lfloor \alpha^n \rfloor $ if $\alpha$ is any number greater than 1?

Comment: A better way to define $a_n$ is as $a_{n+1}:=\left\lfloor\frac{A_{n+1}}{\prod_{k=1}^na_k}\right\rceil$, but although it gets close I think it does not converge because of the reasons in Dolan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not always possible.

Let $A_n=n$ and $p(n)=a_1.a_2....a_n$. Then suppose that, for $n\ge N$, $$0.9<\frac{n}{p(n)}< 1.1$$

Then $\frac{2n}{p(2n)}= \frac{2}{A}\frac{n}{p(n)}$ for some integer $A$. For this to be in the assumed range we require $A=2$ but then $$\frac{n}{p(n)},\frac{2n}{p(2n)},\frac{4n}{p(4n)},...$$  are all constant and so do not tend to $1$.

The only remaining possibility is that, for all sufficiently large $n$, $\frac{n}{p(n)}=1$. But then $p(n)$ does not divide $p(n+1)$.

Comment: Why do you insist on $n/p(n)<1$? At most you can assume $0.9<\frac{n}{p(n)}<1.1$, say.

Comment: @ Chrystomath . Yes, good point. I was thinking of A_n being m.i.